# How do I get the path or directory of my currently-executing script in CSI?

Tags: c#, c#-interactive, csi

What is the best way to get my script’s path from a CSI script? I want to be able to have my script be `#load`ed from a script running in a different directory and still get access to its own directory and not be affected by the working directory. I can’t find anything like nodejs’s [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) constant [in the docs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window#load).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best way I can find to figure out the currently executing script’s directory is quite verbose. I wonder if there is some shortcut/built-in that I do not know about, but here goes:

`GetMineDirectory.csx`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env csi

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

static string GetMyPath(
    [CallerFilePath] string path = "")
    => path;

// Do not write in terms of GetMyPath() in case we are called from another script.
static string GetMyDirectory(
    [CallerFilePath] string path = "")
    => Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

Console.WriteLine($"My full path is {GetMyPath()}");

Console.WriteLine($"My directory is {GetMyDirectory()}");
```